# Lexer and parser for .asm file produced by objdump

Tags: ida, disassembly, disassemblers, compilers, objdump

Is there any existing project that parses the *x86 disassembly file* or **.asm** produced by the objdump or IDA pro using the **lexer and parser** library in python or any other programming language?

Comment: For what purpose? Syntax checking? Logical flow analysis? Compiling into an executable?

Comment: It for generating AST by taking as .asm input than to lift to IR. do you know any exciting projects or link?